# Extract the count of particular macro block types(I, P and S) from the frames in the video

Tags: video-processing, video-compression

How can I extract the count of particular macro block types(I, P and S) from the frames in the video (H.264 and MP4)?
Also, I would like to extract the prediction residual of each of the P and B frames (computed from its corresponding reference frame) in the video from the encoded version itself while the package is decoding it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools to analyze video streams which which can provide slice and macroblock level information:

- [Intel Video Pro Analyzer](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-video-pro-analyzer)
- [Tektronix Video Analyzer](http://www.tek.com/mpeg-test-video/mpeg-analyzer)
- [H264bitstream](https://github.com/aizvorski/h264bitstream)
- [ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Debug/MacroblocksAndMotionVectors) (page Analyzing Macroblock Types)
- [Avidemux](http://www.avidemux.org/admWiki/doku.php?id=tutorial:h.264)

From [How extract Intra-Prediction modes out of h264 stream](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=610), it seems that ffmpeg or ffprobe can do a lot of jobs.